# Don't allow questions to be asked with no title

Tags: bug, status-norepro

This is a bug:

[image]

The OP just wrote the body of their question without actually writing a title. The result, as you can see in the image above, is a singularly useless title. This shouldn't be allowed. If a user posts a question without having typed anything in the title box, a warning should be displayed and the question should not be allowed to be 
posted.

Comment: I'm wondering if something more is going on here, as [we now have another weirdly titled question somewhat like this one](http://askubuntu.com/q/529443/22949). (You may have to check the revision history as it will probably be edited soon.) @AnnaLear

Comment: @eliah That happens if someone has the vote controls selected and hits copy (and then paste). I wouldn't rule out carelessness/stupidity here, but let's keep an eye on this and see if different people keep this up.

Comment: @AnnaLear actually I've hit this bug couple of times (7 times or so that I can recall), but I almost always notice immediately and fix the title thing that in this case didn't happen, and since there's no record of the original one I can't offer practical examples. OH, btw, it normally happen when I close the tab of asking the question and then try to ask again, kind of hit and miss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm fairly sure this is not a bug and that in this instance, the person copied and pasted that text in.

Here's how it's actually laid out:

```
<input id="title" name="title" type="text" maxlength="300" tabindex="100" class="ask-title-field" data-min-length="15" data-max-length="150">                        
<span class="edit-field-overlay">What&#39;s your bug, feature request, or meta-discussion topic? Be specific.</span>
```

Javascript controls the visibility of the span, but there's no default value (or HTML5 placeholder attribute) on the `<input>` field.

Comment: Good grief, holy PEBKAC Batman! That didn't even occur to me.

Comment: Terrible. Just terrible.

Comment: Let's burn the place down... I'll get the kerosene!